# Batch file printing out commands with @echo off

Tags: batch-file, echo, windows-scripting

I am searching for certain XML files and then performing a command on them (`mvn`) which writes an output to a `tree.out` file. If this file is empty then I know there was no output (from `mvn`), so I don't print it.

However, after the first part of the loop execution it prints out from `set size` and then simply prints out the commands of the next loop iterations.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set pomFiles=dir /s/b pom.xml
@echo off

for /f %%f in ('%pomFiles%') do (
    findstr "<packaging>pom</packaging>" %%f > nul
    if errorlevel 0 if not errorlevel 1 (
        cd "%%~dpf"
        mvn -q dependency:tree -Dincludes^=%dependency% -DoutputFile^="%%~dpftree.out"
        for /f %%i in ("%%~dpftree.out") do set size=%%~zi
        if !size! gtr 0 (
            type "%%~dpftree.out"
        )
        del "%%~dpftree.out"        
    )
)
```

I presume there is an error in my code which is causing the statements to print, but I cannot see what the issue is myself.

Comment: is it actually performing the following statements as well as printing them out, or is it ONLY printing them out? Is it possible the `mvn` command is leaving echo turned on afterwards? What happens if you make a minimal test case with `@echo off`, then your `mvn` command, then some other simple batch command?

Comment: @Vicky in the first execution of the loop it prints `set size=170` so it seems to be evaluating. After that it simply prints the entire commands for the next loops without evaluation. Interestingly adding `@echo off` after the `mvn` command did stop the other loops from printing! I think there may still be some issues in my code somewhere, but THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was running the command

`mvn -q dependency:tree -Dincludes^=%dependency% -DoutputFile^="%%~dpftree.out"`

without using the key word **call** before it.

Using

`call mvn -q dependency:tree -Dincludes^=%dependency% -DoutputFile^="%%~dpftree.out"`

stopped the commands being printed.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of `for /f` for files is

```
FOR /F ["options"] %variable IN (file-set) DO command [command-parameters]
```

but in your code the file-set is `("%%~dpftree.out")` which is for strings.

To use double quotes, I think you have to use the usebackq option:

```
for /f "usebackq" %%i in ('%%~dpftree.out') do set size=%%~zi
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your observation! When I change it to your version of the code I'm not sure if `size` is being set correctly though. Straight after the loop I have `echo !size!` and all that prints is `!size!`, not the value of `size`. Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm changing `!size!` to `%size%` seems to have worked, but now the title of the cmd prompt is strangely being changed to the first command in the loop execution `findstr...` after the first execution.

Comment: Sorry, I realise `%size%` only worked because in the command prompt it had been set previously! Do you know what is the right syntax to make sure I get the latest version of `size` for my `if` statement?

Comment: @Alex: You could reset it to some default value (e.g. 0) just after the `mvn` call. Note also that you could actually eliminate the `size` variable altogether. Just don't store the size but do `if %%~zi gtr 0 type whatever` instead directly in the loop body.

Comment: @AndriyM yes thanks, this is what I have ended up doing and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I know this an old thread but I've spent hours looking for an answer which didn't worked for me and this being one of the most popular answers to this question, I'll post it here.

I've noticed that the sintax when `(` or `)` is being used, is really strict. So using an editor like Sublime, or Notepad++, I've found one space char just next to one `)`, in a 500 lines batch, that threw off the `@echo off` statement.

In other words( * being used to visually represent a space at the end of line):

```
IF %randomvar% EQU 1 (*
    goto DO 
) ELSE (
    goto DOELSE
)**
```

Either * or **, will mess `@echo off` and will output every line of code to console.

Just make sure that you don't have any unnecesary chars at the end of lines.

Cheers