# Variable not setting in nested for loop - Windows batch

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, windows-scripting

Below is a simplified snippet of my code:

```
@echo off    
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    for /f %%f in ('%pomFiles%') do (
        findstr "var" %%f > nul
        if errorlevel 0 if not errorlevel 1 (
            cd "%%~dpf"
            for /f "usebackq" %%i in ('%%~dpftree.out') do ( set size=%%~zi && echo !size!)
            if !size! gtr 0 (
                   //do  stuff
            )
        )
    )
```

The `!size!` variable does not seem to be being set. If I do `echo !size!`, it prints `!size!`. How can I make sure `!size!` evaluates?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Batch file printing out commands with @echo off](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14684074/batch-file-printing-out-commands-with-echo-off)

Comment: better to edit your original question as you home in on the problem, rather than post a whole new question.

Comment: @Vicky, I have fixed the issue of the commands printing due to your suggestion which I will mark as an answer if you post it. However I felt this was a completely different issue...

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are using `for /f`, which is to read the contents of a file, hence the problem is you are trying to get the size of the variable `%%i`, which is set as the first line in the file.

You just need a regular `for` loop

```
for %%i in ("%%~dpftree.out") do ( set size=%%~zi && echo !size!)
if !size! gtr 0 (
    //do  stuff
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Bali C, but even with this code change it still seems to print out `!size!` rather than the value. If I write `echo %%~zi` the size does print...

Comment: Hmm, you have enabled delayed expansion haven't you? I know it's in your example, but it sounds like you don't. I just tested it and it works fine for me?

Comment: Yes, it is the first line before the first for-loop as shown in my example. That should enable delayed expansion for the inner-loop as well right? Given your proposed new for statement, is it sufficient to put the `if !size! gtr 0` in the body of the for loop and change `!size!` for `%%~zi`? This loop will only every run once, right?

Comment: Yeah, as long as it's there it should work. In theory yes that should work fine, try that without assigning it to `size` first.